# WinUI 3 Desktop Navigation View Page

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a `NavigationView` in my main `Window` which manages the `Page`s in my application. The first `Page`, which is displayed in a `Frame`, will be a login screen. I want to disable the navigation menu and enable it when user's login is successful.  My problem is: how can I access the navigation menu in the `Frame` (the `Page` in the frame `FMMain`)?

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NVMenu" PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact" IsSettingsVisible="False" IsPaneOpen="False">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="NVIHome" x:Name="NVIHome">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon x:Uid="FIHome"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="FMMain" />
</NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a global static property, which your login frame can access.  Then, bind the 'Enabled' property of your Navigation view item to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder under the project: "Views"

Then add an empty page (C# - WinUI - Blank Page) and rename it.

Now the project folder looks like this:

- Project Name

  - Properties
  - Assets
  - Views

    - BlankPage1.xaml

      - BlankPage1.xaml.cs
    - BlankPage2.xaml

      - BlankPage2.xaml.cs
  - App.xaml

    - App.xaml.cs
  - MainWindow.xaml

    - MainWindow.xaml.cs

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<NavigationView IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" IsSettingsVisible="False" ItemInvoked="nav_iteminvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Page1" Tag="WinUI3.Views.BlankPage1"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Page2" Tag="WinUI3.Views.BlankPage1"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
```

Change the "WinUI3" in navigation view item tags to your project name.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;

private void nav_iteminvoked(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
        {
            Type newPage = Type.GetType(args.InvokedItemContainer.Tag.ToString());
            contentFrame.Navigate(newPage, null, args.RecommendedNavigationTransitionInfo);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't do that, winui3 is not production ready. I am strugling with many issues.
To name a few - scrollview does not work properly (does not work at all, to be specific), badges are not implemented yet, window icon must be set with win32, if you need data table, community toolkit is only free way, but it does not support net6 yet...

Comment: You need to answer the question if you can, don't just say not to do something. You don't know why they are doing it.

Comment: You can also get a free DataGrid with DevExpress for WinUI, which totally supports .NET 6 and latest WinUI.